# Preallocation in r

Tags: r, performance

In Matlab it is drilled into you - preallocate, preallocate, preallocate. If you fail to do this, gremlins will eat cpu cycles and you will be a bad person. Is it as important to preallocate in r as it is in Matlab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since in R we tend to avoid explicit loops, it is not as important. Many functions do it under the hood for us. Of course, if you insist on using `for` loops, you should pre-allocate to avoid growing an object in a loop (which is one of the slowest operations you can do).  Relevant reading material: [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Seems good. Also I like the style of the linked text. Will read through.

Answer (score 2):

some examples

```
test1=function(){
  l=list()
  for(i in 1:10000){
    l=append(l,"abc")
  }
  return(l)
}
system.time(test1()) # 2.367 sec

test2=function(){
  l=vector("list", 10000)
  for(i in 1:10000){
    l[i]="abc"
  }
  return(l)
}
system.time(test2()) # 0.015 sec

test3=function(){
  l=list()
  for(i in 1:10000){
    l[i]="abc"
  }
  return(l)
}
system.time(test3()) # 0.309 sec

test4=function(){
  return(lapply(1:10000, function(x) "abc"))   
}
system.time(test4()) # 0.003
```

R for loops suck indeed :)

which is problematic, cause its not always readable to change it into a lappy

Comment: And now add `lapply(seq_len(1e4), function(x) "abc")` to the comparison.

Comment: system.time(seq_len(1e8)) # 0.094
    system.time(1:100000000) # 0.091

Comment: `seq_len` is internally very similar to `:`. It doesn't make sense to compare timing of them. I was suggesting to compare `lapply` to your `for` loops, which you did. And `for` loops don't suck. They are the right tool, if you need a loop with side effects. The rule of thumb is: Use R loops if there is no vectorised alternative. You need a return value and iterations are independent, you use `*apply`. You need a side effect like plotting, you should use a `for` loop. Otherwise, you get creative or use Rcpp.

Comment: what sucks is that the time difference is 5-100x

Comment: It's about a factor of 5. If you grow an object in it, it's not a fault of the looping construct.

Comment: the factor 5 is if you preallocate the space... so no growing involved... with growing it becomes the 100x or do i misunderstand you

Comment: Correct. *In your test case* `lapply` is more efficient by a factor of 5 than a `for` loop with pre-allocation (which is the only correct way to use a `for` loop with a return object).